# JavaScript - req.body.username is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I am VERY new with JS, Angular.js and node.js. I am trying to do login-register project and I have a little problem.

This is my code:

**login.ctrl.js:**

```
var app = angular.module('login-register', []);

app.factory('UserLog', ['$http', function ($http) {
    return {
        loginUser: function (user, callback) {
            $http.get('/user', user)
            .success(function (data, status) {
                callback(data, false);
            }).
            error(function (data, status) {
                callback(data, true);
            });
        }
    }
}]);

app.controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope', 'UserLog', function ($scope, UserLog) {
    $scope.logUser = function () {
        var user = {
            'username': $scope.username,
            'password': $scope.password
        };
        UserLog.loginUser(user, function (result, error) {
            if (error) {
                window.alert('Error finding user in DB');
                return;
            }
            if (!result) {
                window.alert('Invalid username or password');
                return;
            }
            window.location.href = "views/chat_screen.html";
        });
    }
}]);
```

**server.js:**

```
app.get('/user', function (req, res) {
    // Find user by userName
    User.findOne({ username: req.body.username }, function (err, userById) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        if (!userById) return console.log('user was not found');
        res.send(userById);
    })
});
```

('User' is schema of mongoose).

When I run this code, `req.body.username` is undefined.
some of you can explain me how to do it right..?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using "get" request and it cannot send body with request, use "post" request type to send body elements.